# Why does my OGL program fail to run on WIndows 8?

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, glfw

I have a small and basic C++ program that I built in Visual Studio 2012 that uses GLFW and OpenGL but whenever my friend tries to run it on her Windows 8 Machine, it crashes immediately with no extra information (just says 'program has stopped running')

Now the command window for the program does open, which precedes the actual glfw window which does not open.  So I'm thinking maybe it's failing the init or window opening itself?

A few details:

- The version she was has was built in release.
- Win8 machine is 64 bit,   program is built on a x64 machine for 32
- I statically linked /MT into the build so there shouldnt be any missing msvc dll issues
- This required me to rebuild GLFW to statically link it as well
- I'm not using any other libraries, the only thing added to the linker input is "glfw3.lib;opengl32.lib;glu32.lib"

And finally here's an excerpt of my window creation code:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, 0);
m_window = glfwCreateWindow(winSize.x, winSize.y, windowName.c_str(), NULL, NULL);

if(!m_window)
    throw std::exception("Window failed to create");

glfwGetFramebufferSize(m_window, &m_windowSize.x, &m_windowSize.y);
glfwMakeContextCurrent(m_window);
```

Any thoughts of things I can try?  I can upload the exe if anyone wants to try it on their machine.

Comment: Is `GLFW_RESIZABLE` really and truly the only window hint you are passing? The API documentation seems to indicate you need to call `glfwDefaultWindowHints (...)`. The language is a little vague, in that this could mean the defaults are never initialized or that they are simply not reset after creation: *Hints are no longer reset to their default values on window creation. To set default hint values, use `glfwDefaultWindowHints (...)`.* That said, if GLFW3 is only able to get a GDI pixel format it will fail to create a window, I cannot imagine this happening on a Win8 machine; you never know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell your friend to install the graphics drivers downloaded from the GPU maker's website. The graphics drivers shipping with Windows itself lack proper OpenGL support.